# Is there a way I can be notified when Windows Explorer is done copying / moving a file?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, copy-paste

Obviously, this is a very common operation, but I'm annoyed that Windows will not tell me when it is done. I either need to see if the copy / move progress bar still exists, or (worse) look to see if it has disappeared.

Is there a way for me to get notified when the copy / move operation is complete? A simple dialog box would be great.

BTW, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SU! This is a good question and I agree with you, there should be a balloon notification or something to notify us... Maybe windows 10 will have a fix...

Comment: Whenever I copy anything in W7 i get a dialog box with progress bar.

Comment: This is so true I completely agree

Comment: I would have thought that copy / move action would be logged in the [Event Viewer](http://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/) (allowing me to trigger a dialog box after the fact), but I don't see a record anywhere. Hmmm. There must be a way.

Comment: Using "fastcopy" with the option of having a wave file played at both error, and finish has worked out great here, especially for long term copy/move operations.  an online TTS to make the speech to fully inform and be different from bings and doinks.  I still use the windows one for quick moves and operations where comparison is unneeded. terracopy also does some kind of beeping to indicate failed or finished too.

Comment: write a feedback (or upvote an existing one), the MS team will look at it if many people do it.

Comment: there might be a way with autohotkey (it can do anything)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Shutter](http://www.den4b.com/products/shutter). I used to use it for shutting down my PC when a particular task is completed. You can use other functions supported by this tool.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a native Windows solution.

Comment: Too bad there isn't a Linux version of this.  It would be a solution for my own problem (http://superuser.com/questions/933863/how-to-delay-a-system-sound-in-debian-kde).

Comment: @fixer1234, if you are looking for tasks that can be run from terminal, you can check this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/409611/desktop-notification-when-long-running-commands-complete)

Comment: That won't work for the current problem, but it looks like it could be useful for other stuff.  Thanks.